# CordovaJS - ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I've been trying for 2 days now to get my Cordova app to build for Android. Each time I open my project in Android Studio I get the following during gradle sync during the run tasks phase:

```
ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [__tested_artifact__::CordovaLib]/Users/userName/Downloads/MyApp(1.2.5)/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/library_manifest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 1

Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 1, or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19, or use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

I've looked through many solutions and none seem to correct my issue. I've adjusted settings in the manifests of my built project and also in the `cordova.android` `node_modules` folder as so:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
```

I've added the various values in my config.xml:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28"/>
```

As well as instructed Cordova to build specific versions:

```
cordova platform add android@7.0.0
```

And I still receive the same error, though the values (19 and 1, that is) don't change even when the numbers are changed.

In addition, I've created a new blank project and built it with the same results. The same project builds fine on an old machine of mine, but the Play Store says that it's outdated and is a security risk.

One additional thing of note that could be of help: when Cordova builds, I see the following during the process:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/userName/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
```

Comment: Could be an old plugin using minSDKVersion 1. I would re-evaluate the plugins first.

Comment: I removed all plugins, removed the platform, added it once more, and the same is still happening. It seems to occur during gradle sync "run tasks" step, if that helps.

Comment: What minSDKVersion do you see in `/platforms/android/build.gradle` ?

Comment: min is 19, target and compile are 28.

Comment: It's hard to blindly tell where the problem is. I would try to remove the android platform, delete node_modules folder then run npm install and recreate the platform.

Comment: Done, same thing. BUT I removed the defining lines in both the android manifests (the one in app and in cordovaLib) and it compiled and worked properly. Strangely enough the play store says that it's target version is 19. Which I am quite puzzled about. Also, if I can provide anymore information for clarity, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me was, first

remove android platform

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
```

then add the android platform as follows

```
ionic cordova platform add android@nightly
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks, friend! You saved me a lot of time and stress!

Comment: friend, do you help me? I have an application but it does not ask for permissions when starting for the first time. Did something like this ever happen to you?

regards

Comment: I haven't come across that, no. But this is certainly the site to as about it. Sorry I couldn't help you.